# Tips to debug React production build code on local environment

Tags: reactjs, production-environment

We have a React application that is running on production. The app works perfectly fine locally but we are facing some problems in production mode. i.e., when we build the code locally for production, the issues are still reproducible.

Is there any way to debug production-built code locally?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create production build
   `npm run build`  (build files into folder /bundle)
2. npm i -g http-server
   and run

`http-server bundler` (your folder)

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think this answer has room for improvement. If it contained a more specific example, e.g., based on Create React App (CRA), then the answer would be move valuable. For example "http-server" is not necessarily available, so needs to be installed. However, it would also be useful to understand what is meant by "your folder", e.g., which folder is "your folder" here? Is it "dist" or "src" etc?